# Is it possible to create a transparent container in easeljs?

Tags: graphics, html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

I would like to create a circle container that is transparent - revealing the background underneath, and populate with other elements that are not transparent. I would like the elements in the container to be clickable. What is the best way to achieve this with Easel/Create js?

Comment: I am not sure quite what you mean -- are you trying to mask content using a circle? Try creating a Circle using Graphics/Shape, and setting it as the `mask` on any display object.

Comment: Thanks Lanny, what I ended up doing- and maybe there is a better solution, was using two canvases. One as a background to draw an image on, and one as a foreground. Foreground started out as a white rectangle. I added a circle container and set compositeOperation = 'destination-out', so the circle was cut out from foreground, revealing the background. Then I added elements to the circle container, and added eventListeners to the elements.

Comment: I've been wondering this same thing recently, @R Jarvis, and came across your question entirely by accident! I know this question is kind of old, but could you share the code you used?